# Alternative to nonlocal for local variables in a function with nested functions in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, parsing, state-machine, generator

### Introduction for future readers

I posted the code below in the hope that it would be a good example to discuss
the topic "Alternative to nonlocal for local variables in a function with nested
functions in Python".

As it turns out, the answer to that question depends a lot on whether or not the
hypothetical function with nested functions would return an value/object or not.

For the case when it would not, you can find a consise and clear discussion
[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064953/using-a-class-as-a-container-object-for-local-variables-as-an-alternative-to-no).
For people who don't know about "nonlocal", that discussion also consisely
clarifies the topic, and what I generally mean by alternatives to nonlocal.

For the case with a return value/object, the next question is whether or not
that return value/object needs to provide a class interface, typically methods
to access its contents. If it does, which is likely if the problem at hand is
complex enough to justify a function with nested functions, the hypothetical
function should not be implemented as a function but as a class, and the
accessor methods to the hypothetical return value would simply be methods in
that class. I.e. the problem becomes a classical class design problem.

This is the case for the code below, as shown in 200_success' and my answer.

The example itself is a tokenizer for a simple arithmetic expression. For the
sake of simplicity, the code includes no error handling.

**Please note that the alternatives provided in this question are not good solutions. 200_success' and my answer below provide good solutions, although error handling would need to be added.**

### Alternatives

**Alternative one: class self**

```
OPERATORS = '+', '-', '*', '/'

def tokenize(expression):
    def state_none(c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token = c
            self.state = state_number
        elif c in OPERATORS:
            self.token = 'operator', c
            self.token_ready = True

    def state_number(c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token += c
        else:
            self.char_consumed = False
            self.token = 'number', self.token
            self.token_ready = True
            self.state = state_none

    def interpret_character(c):
        self.token_ready = False
        self.char_consumed = True
        self.state(c)

    class self:
        token_ready = False
        token = None
        char_consumed = True
        state = state_none

    for c in expression:
        self.char_consumed = False
        while not self.char_consumed:
            interpret_character(c)
            if self.token_ready:
                yield self.token
    if self.state == state_number:
        yield 'number', self.token

def main():
    for x in tokenize('15+ 2 * 378 / 5'):
        print(x)

    # ('number', '15')
    # ('operator', '+')
    # ('number', '2')
    # ('operator', '*')
    # ('number', '378')
    # ('operator', '/')
    # ('number', '5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Alternative two: callable class**

I do not like it because one has to first instantiate the class in order to call
the object, but it is a clear inspiration for alternative one.

```
OPERATORS = '+', '-', '*', '/'

class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.expression = expression
        self.token_ready = False
        self.token = None
        self.char_consumed = True
        self.state = self.state_none

    def state_none(self, c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token = c
            self.state = self.state_number
        elif c in OPERATORS:
            self.token = 'operator', c
            self.token_ready = True

    def state_number(self, c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token += c
        else:
            self.char_consumed = False
            self.token = 'number', self.token
            self.token_ready = True
            self.state = self.state_none

    def interpret_character(self, c):
        self.token_ready = False
        self.char_consumed = True
        self.state(c)

    def __call__(self):
        for c in self.expression:
            self.char_consumed = False
            while not self.char_consumed:
                self.interpret_character(c)
                if self.token_ready:
                    yield self.token
        if self.state == self.state_number:
            yield 'number', self.token

def main():
    for x in Tokenizer('15+ 2 * 378 / 5')():
        print(x)

    # ('number', '15')
    # ('operator', '+')
    # ('number', '2')
    # ('operator', '*')
    # ('number', '378')
    # ('operator', '/')
    # ('number', '5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize 200_success' answer, I should implement the iterator interface in a class, instead of trying to return a generator.

My code ported to that pattern follows. That version of the code also includes a proper handling of expression termination, which was missing in my initial code.

**Good alternative: a class that implements the expected interface**

```
OPERATORS = '+', '-', '*', '/'

class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.token = None
        self.char_consumed = True
        self.state = Tokenizer._state_none
        self.expression = iter(expression)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def _state_none(self, c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token = c
            self.state = Tokenizer._state_number
        elif c in OPERATORS:
            return 'operator', c

    def _state_number(self, c):
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.token += c
        else:
            self.char_consumed = False
            self.state = Tokenizer._state_none
            return 'number', self.token

    def _interpret_character(self, c):
        self.char_consumed = True
        return self.state(self, c)

    def __next__(self):
        for c in self.expression:
            self.char_consumed = False
            while not self.char_consumed:
                token = self._interpret_character(c)
                if token:
                    return token
        token = self._interpret_character('') # termination event
        if token:
            return token
        raise StopIteration

def main():
    for x in Tokenizer('15+ 2 * 378 / 5'):
        print(x)

    # ('number', '15')
    # ('operator', '+')
    # ('number', '2')
    # ('operator', '*')
    # ('number', '378')
    # ('operator', '/')
    # ('number', '5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main difference with 200_success' solution is that my states do not take care of the fetching of events. The code driving the [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) does that instead. This means that my `__next__()` method is heavier, but my states are lighter. I also do not need a specific terminating state. I made that design choice out of habit (I like to keep my states as free from non-FSM logic as possible), but it has the additional benefit to provide cheaper scaling of the state machine.

Also, since the solution is a regular class, I see no reason for not using the traditional class naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations for recognizing that it is sometimes undesirable to write classes in Python.  A rule of thumb is, if a class has two methods, one of which is the constructor, then consider writing a function instead.  Such is the case with `tokenize()`.

However, your first implementation, which uses `self` as a hack to mutate non-local variables, feels icky.  Your object-oriented implementation is easier to understand, though more awkward to call.  So, we just need to fix its call interface.

Next, you should [recognize](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) that

> Generators are a simple and powerful tool for creating iterators.

What you want is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).  What you do not want is to write it as a generator.  (Generators often offer an advantage in simplicity because they implicitly retain information in the suspended state of execution. But that doesn't help you if you want to write an explicit state machine.)  Instead, you should write it as a class that implements the `__next__()` and `__iter__()` methods.

There is a minor issue, that classes are typically named using `UpperCase`, whereas functions are typically named using `lower_case`.  Here, I would recommend breaking that convention, and naming the class as if it were a function.  One of the underappreciated features of Python is that there is no `new` keyword; the distinction between functions and classes can be blurred (such as in the case of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)).

---

I would change the way your state machine is driven.

Awkwardness arises in the way the final state is reached.  Actually, you don't have a formal final state.  What you have instead is this hack at the end of your `__call__()`, which should ideally be in the `state_number()` method instead:

> ```
>         if self.state == self.state_number:
>             yield 'number', self.token
> ```

Rather than having the main loop be responsible for iterating through the characters and feeding them to the state handlers, I would have each state handler voluntarily consume a character from the stream.

In the implementation below, I set the state to `None` to indicate that the final state has been reached.  To avoid confusion, I have renamed `state_none()` to `_state_neutral()`.  Also, instead of `token` and `token_ready`, I use `partial_token` to store digits of a possibly incomplete number.  Complete tokens are returned immediately, rather than being temporarily stored.

```
OPERATORS = ('+', '-', '*', '/')

class tokenize:
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.expr_iter = iter(expression)
        self.state = tokenize._state_neutral
        self.partial_token = ''

    def _state_neutral(self):
        c = self.partial_token or next(self.expr_iter)
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.state = tokenize._state_number
            self.partial_token = c
        elif c in OPERATORS:
            self.partial_token = ''
            return ('operator', c)
        else:
            # TODO: Error handling for illegal characters
            self.partial_token = ''

    def _state_number(self):
        try:
            c = next(self.expr_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            self.state = None
            return ('number', self.partial_token)
        if c.isdecimal():
            self.partial_token += c
        else:
            n = self.partial_token
            self.state = tokenize._state_neutral
            self.partial_token = c
            return ('number', n)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.state:
            token = self.state(self)
            if token:
                return token
        raise StopIteration

def main():
    for token in tokenize('15+ 2 * 378 / 5'):
        print(token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```